# Non-Apple methods to administer XRAID?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, apple, raid

I've got an older Apple XRAID, and in order to administer it, I've had to rely on the Apple XRAID software utility that is native only on OSX. My only Mac laptop is going to be heading the way of the dinosaur soon, and I'd love to have another way to address this piece of hardware.

Has anyone found, used, or even heard of a software solution for admining these things without a Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run the Xserve RAID Admin on Windows without any problems - you can download the .zip version from Apple's site.  I'd post a link but apparently I'm not cool enough yet.

See [Using RAID Admin with other operating systems](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21268?viewlocale=en_US) and the download is at [support.apple.com](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/application_updates/xserveraidadmintools151.html)

Comment: That's terrific. Thanks very much. The first link is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

The XRAID utility is written in java, it may be possible (although I haven't tried) to jumpstart it on a linux machine. The actual interface to the XRAID utility is a variant of webmin over http, on a non standard port.

My suggestion your be to look in the `info.plist` file for hints about the command line arguments that are passed by the finder when it launches

You could also check out [lithium](http://www.lithiumcorp.com/), a 3rd party monitoring solution designed to work with the XRAID

Answer (score 2):

At work I have ~20 XRAIDS.  First of all, I feel your pain :)

Download the RAID Admin tool from Apple.  It's written in Java, and you can run it under Linux pretty easily.  (as in, "java (whatever).jar")  I would strongly suggest not letting it remember the IPs of all of your XRAIDS, it seems to query them all periodically, without letting the GUI update (this could be a problem with the old version of Java I'm running it on too.  Try it and let me know?)

It will ask you for your read and write passwords when it needs them, and can save them.  If you just unboxed the things, their passwords are "public" and "private" respectively.  I suspect that it's all SNMP under the hood, but I haven't verified that.

If you're not running the latest firmware, upgrade ASAP.  The older one that all of mine came with had a bug where it would occasionally forget how to use the Ethernet port.  Being that you admin it over that Ethernet... bad.

Good luck!

Comment: The XRAID does respond to SNMP, but it's mib is virtually useless :(

Comment: s/mib is// , in the case of those XRAIDs. :(